# How to use Object key as header and values child lists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a simple json file which includes mathematical operational information. I want to lis json data into inside ul, so that, object key should be header with header class, and its values should list after the each header.

My script file:

```
{
  "Operations":{
   " Arithmetic Operations" : ["+", "-", "*", "/"],
   "Comparision Operations" : ["Equals","Greater than","Greater than equal to","Less than","Less than equal to"]
  }
}

fetch('./js/data.json')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    fetchList(data['Operations'])
  });

fetchList = data => {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    let list;
    values.forEach(item => {
      list = `<li class="list">${ item }</li>`;
    });

    const li =
      `<li class="head">${ key }</li>
        ${ list }
    `;

    console.log(li)
    document.querySelector('#operations .lists').innerHTML += li
  });
}
```

Result shows only last values of each one

```
<li class="head"> Arithmetic Operations</li>
<li class="list">/</li>
<li class="head">Comparision Operations</li>
<li class="list">Less than equal to</li>
```

Comment: `list = ` just overwrites the value each time. I think you meant to use `+=` rather than `=`, after first initialising `list` to an empty string.

Comment: I would say that comment from Robin is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no dupes, I'll answer it. There are two things here.

1. Replace: `=`
2. Append: `+=`

What you're doing is replacing. What you need to be doing is appending. Your solution is:

```
let list = "";
values.forEach(item => {
  list += `<li class="list">${ item }</li>`;
});
```

An example snippet to show you what's happening will be:

```js
var arr = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

var one = "";
arr.forEach(function (a) {
  one = a;
});
console.log(one);

var two = "";
arr.forEach(function (a) {
  two += a;
});
console.log(two);
```

I hope you understand the cases above with the variables `one` and `two`. You're looking for `two` but you have implemented `one`.